# Tabula does not recognize table

Tags: python, tabula

I have a simple python program that takes in a pdf (with a table) and saves the data into a csv file using tabula:

```
import tabula

if __name__ == '__main__':
path = input('Filename: ')

pathSegments = path.split('/')

folder = ''

i = 0
while i < len(pathSegments)-1:
    folder += '/' + pathSegments[i]
    i += 1

name = pathSegments[len(pathSegments)-1].split('.')[0]
dest = folder + '/' + name + '.csv'
print(dest)

tabula.convert_into(path, dest, pages = "all", output_format = "csv")
```

I tried multiple different pdfs, for example one with the following picture:
[image]

The result however, is always an empty csv file, tabula does not seem to recognize the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabula isn't perfect at picking up tables. I would look into adding a templates to give tabula more guidance. These templates could by dynamically generated depending on different features of the document. See the function `tabula.read_pdf_with_template` as documented here: https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf_with_template.